# Making headings that have interesting formatting readable by screen readers

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria

Say you want to stylise some heading tags to make them "01_Hosting" instead of "1. Hosting", how do you make this accessible to screen readers?

Take the snippet:

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="section__title">
    <h2>04_Hosting</h2>
    <h3>speedy</h3>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

With styling like:

[image: small 04_HOSTING tag black background, above speedy title]

I initially thought to do

```html
<h2 aria-label="4. Hosting">04_Hosting</h2>
```

but afaik `aria-label` is meant for interactive elements only. I also tried it with my screen reader (Orca) and it ignored the label.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but isn't "04_Hosting" available to screen readers in your example?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Sorry, yes it is. It's just that it is read out in full which maybe makes it a bit unclear, whereas visually it makes sense.

This example is something from my own website, but I'm also looking for a more general solution to the issue of something being clear to people who can see, but unclear when read out in full to a screen reader user.

Comment: So you're basically trying to get it to read something other than exactly what is being displayed, got it. Apologies, I didn't understand what you were asking.

Comment: `aria-label` will also apply to heading elements, as they are widely considered "user interface elements" by browser manufacturers. It doesn't have to be strictly interactive elements. You can test this using DevTools in your browser.

Comment: @Josh Seems to vary, given the default SR on Linux (Orca) does not announce labels for headings

Comment: @JP - It does seem difficult to get good browser support metrics for `aria-label` as it applies to headers. I tested using NVDA on windows using Chrome, FF, and Edge. All worked as anticipated. My understanding of Orca (from the WebAIM survey results) is that it's not very full-featured and not widely used.

Comment: @Josh, heading elements "are widely considered "user interface elements""?  Do you have a reference for that? The "official" definition of "user interface component" with respect to WCAG is https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#dfn-user-interface-components, which is essentially an interactive element.  So `aria-label` will not be honored on a heading more often than not.

Comment: @slugolicious - I realized after posting that, I'm not entirely sure how correct that it, but I did actually test it using a range of browsers and the screen reader that I have available to me. I also posted a follow-up regarding the testing. Do you have any metrics to share and contribute to this discussion? Or did you just feel the need to point out that someone else may be incorrect without any evidence to support that?

Comment: @Josh I provided the official spec (w3.org) that defines what a user interface widget is, which does not include headings.  There's also an official guideline on where `aria-label` is supported, also from w3.org - https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support.  The 7th bullet point specifically says to not use `aria-label` on headings.

Comment: @slugolicious - thanks, Glen! That's something useful. You're so smart!!!!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not a good idea to tell the numbers to screen reader users as the heading number will be read out as well, and the number is not likely to be hugely relevant.

If it is really important you can do

```html
<h2 class="accent-heading">
  <span aria-hidden=true>0</span>4<span aria-hidden=true>_</span>
  Hosting
</h2>
```

Otherwise, this can probably be solved simply with

```html
<h2 class="accent-heading"><span aria-hidden="true">04_</span>Hosting</h2>
```

Comment: If the numbers are helpful for sighted users, they'll be helpful for people using assistive technologies. Always try to create the same experience for all users, rather than separate equivalent ones.

Comment: Indeed, which is why I presented both options

Comment: I was addressing your first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<h2 class="accent-heading" aria-hidden="true">04_Hosting</h2>
<h2 class="sr-only">4. Hosting</h2>
```

```css
.sr-only {
  height: 1px; 
  width: 1px; 
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  top: -10px; 
}
```

Seems like a possible solution inspired by https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20120103/C7

However, this seems to be bad practice as I get the warning

> A11y: h2 element should not be hidden | svelte(a11y-hidden)